endomorphisms on product space
I was wondering how we show that endomorphisms $F$ on $(\mathbb{P}^1)^n$ must be of the form $$F(x_1,...,x_n)=(f_1(x_{\sigma(1)},...,f_n(x_{\sigma(n)}))$$ where $\sigma$ is the permutation of $1,2,...,n$ and each $f_i$ rational maps.

The nef cone in the Picard group of $(\mathbb{P}^1)^n$ is generated by the pullbacks $H_1,\dots,H_n$ of the ample generators of the factors. Therefore, every automorphism must preserve the set of $H_i$, hence induces a permutation. This gives a morphism
$$
\phi \colon \mathrm{Aut}((\mathbb{P}^1)^n) \to \mathfrak{S}_n,
$$
which is bviously surjective. On the other hand, any automorphism in the kernel of this morphism preserves each of the $H_i$, hence induces an automorphism of each linear systems $|H_i| \cong \mathbb{P}^1$. This gives a morphism
$$
\psi \colon \mathrm{Ker}(\phi) \to \prod_{i=1}^n \mathrm{PGL}_2.
$$
Finally, it is easy to see that every automorphism in the kernel is trivial.

Please don't answer no-effort questions. The reasons are explained here.
